# UINavigationBar background color not changing for a specific view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibackgroundcolor

I have a global setting at the start of the app that makes the navigation bar white with black buttons like this:

```
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
            buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            appearance.buttonAppearance = buttonAppearance
            appearance.doneButtonAppearance = buttonAppearance

            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
            UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        } else {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        }
```

It works well, now the issue I have one specific viewcontroller where I want the navigation bar to be another color but nothing seems to work.
I tried all of the following in viewDidLoad :

```
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .red //1

            let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
            buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            appearance.buttonAppearance = buttonAppearance
            appearance.doneButtonAppearance = buttonAppearance

            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red //2

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red //3
```

I checked the various questions related to navigationbar colors but they all seems to suggest the same things that don't work.

Using Xcode 15.2 iOS 17.2

Comment: If you want specific viewcontroller, then use it's appearance properties directly, don't need to change globals appearance singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The `UINavigationBar.appearance()` proxy is *global* and affects *all navigation bars that have not been created yet*. Neither of those is what you want. You want to affect just *one* navigation bar, which *does* already exist. So in your second code, instead of

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

and so on, say

```
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
```

and so on. This will set the appearance of your navigation bar just in the case where this view controller is appearing.